# Recording USB digital output (24-bit A/D)

Tags: sensor, sampling, vibration

I have found a [2-channel, USB-powered, ICP® sensor signal conditioner with USB digital output (24-bit A/D)](https://www.pcb.com/products?m=485B39). It is supposed to provide me with a digital output that I should be capable to read from my computer. What software could provide me with a row data output file such as .wav?

Comment: By "row data output file" do you mean *raw*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasheet says that's a usb audio device, so any audio software can give you a .WAV.

You could buy another usb sound card for a few dollars. Consider carefully if you need to spend $1000 for that device.

Edit: Although it does +/-10V output, so that probably explains the higher cost.

Comment: It's slightly unique in the sense that it can provide constant-votlage or constant-current "excitation" to the inputs, whatever that is.

Comment: it provides the sensor with the current for the internal charge amplifier so it seems to be more expensive. @user1850479 how you figured out the price? I have not seen it...

Comment: @GideonKogan: Your own link goes to a page that says "$950.00 USD (Pricing valid in US only)".

Comment: @DaveTweed, it seems that you see different pages regarding to your location. Maybe I can go around it using VPN...